# How to send plain text in POST request through API Gateway AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm newbie in whole AWS universe and I'm trying to make a simple/test API.
I'b like to send a plain text in a body of POST request but I can't.

The request - https://976c9euh34.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/moves/send

I get response:

```
{
    "message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unrecognized token \'test\': was expecting \'null\', \'true\', \'false\' or NaN\n at [Source: (byte[])\"test\"; line: 1, column: 9]"
}
```

if I send POST with "test" body. I've tried put `Content-Type: plain/text` or plain/html but failed.
In the lambda I do not try to work with json. Let's say that now my lambda looks like this:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    file_path = str(time.time()) + '.txt'
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    data = "hello world"
    try:
        s3_response = s3.put_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key=file_path, Body=data)
    except Exception as e:
        raise IOError(e)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': {
            'data': data
        }
    }
```

I see some related parameters in Integration Request like

[image: Integration Request parameter]

but they don't affect at all.

How should I handle this issue? Where do I need to look at?

**UPD:**

The mapping alert:

[image]

*PS: if I put json body it works fine*

Comment: Your mapping template has an alert; can you share it?

Comment: I think the easiest way to do this is with a proxy. Those mapping templates are confusing. You can read about them here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integration-passthrough-behaviors.html

Comment: @jmp thank you! It've helped.